# Azure management certificate is not working

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

we create azure management certiicate both using "makecert" and using IIS7..And uploaded it in the azure site also.But noting seems to be working .Is there any other reason behind this?

API throws 403 errors.Powershell cmdlets throws Authentication failed error.

Answer (score 2):

Working with different certificate file types and the various parameters to makecert can be a bit confusing.  Ultimately, you need to upload a CER file (does not contain private key) to the management portal for management API authentication, and use a PFX (contains private key) for signing requests.

When you need to use SSL, you need to upload a PFX file to your hosted service via the management portal, the management API, or you can use a tool like one of Cerebrata's.

We use the following batch file to create our certificate files (replace CAPS_HERE text):

```
makecert -r -pe -a sha1 -n "CN=CERTIFICATE_NAME_HERE" -ss My -len 2048 -sp "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -sy 24 CER_FILE_NAME_HERE.cer
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=CERTIFICATE_NAME_HERE" -sky exchange "CER_FILE_NAME_HERE.cer" -sv "PVK_FILE_NAME_HERE.pvk" 
pvk2pfx -pvk "PVK_FILE_NAME_HERE.pvk" -spc "CER_FILE_NAME_HERE.cer" -pfx "PVK_FILE_NAME_HERE.pfx" -pi PASSWORD_HERE
```

Additionally, some links:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2010/11/05/ssl-certificates.aspx

http://www.lombard.me/2008/03/summary-of-x509-certificate-file-types.html

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770735.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to download a publishsettings file - this automatically configures a certificate public key in your azure subscription and downloads the cert to your machine.

You can use Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile to download a publishsettings file, or log in at:

https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index?client=powershell